# Wordpress plugin (Q&A Lite by WPMU Dev) not working once logged out from the Wordpress admin account

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins

I just installed the Wordpress plugin (Q&A Lite by WPMU Dev). However, once I save it, it works as long as I'm logged in my Wordpress account but it does not appear once logged out from the Wordpress admin account. Instead, it just takes me back to the homepage. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of WordPress are you running with the Q&A Lite plugin?

If you look at Questions>Settings and scroll down do you see an area for "Accessibility Settings"?  In this area you can assign what user roles can take certain actions within the Q&A plugin.

Make sure you have the abilities for "Visitor" setup the way you want (such as being able to view questions and create answers).  That should get you up and running.